# Counting number of jobs for each month

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running this query to get the delivery date for jobs. Each job has a leader and I'm running this query to display all jobs for each leader and the delivery date for each job.

```
SELECT job_num, 
       firstname, 
       lastname,
       extra_date 
FROM view_job_info 
INNER JOIN view_leader_users ON view_job_info.mm_id = view_leader_users.id
  WHERE (DATEDIFF(NOW(), latest_workorder_date) < 200  //This is a check for active jobs
     OR (DATEDIFF(NOW(), posted_date) < 200))          //Same as above
     AND job_num > 2000 AND firstname LIKE 'mike'
     ORDER BY mm_id, deliverydate DESC
```

Sample output:

[image]

So how can I get the number of jobs for each month for Mike.

So if you look at the table, there are 4 jobs for February and I'm trying to display this on the page as

Jobs for user Mike Easter:

- January  : 4
- February : 4
- March    : 1

I tried using count() on extra_date but that just gives me the total number of rows for Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `group by` with your count. Something like:

```
select name, count(*) from view_job_info
  where name = 'mike'
  group by MONTH(extra_date)
```

Comment: That worked! 

I did this. SELECT job_num, firstname, lastname, month(extra_date) as month, count(*) as job_count then group by month(extra_date)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
GROUP BY firstname, MONTH(extra_date)
```